# File address of the server

Tags: php

How to find the address of the server that contains the files?

for example:

```
/home/hosting/helloworld/public_html/
```

Is it possible to print it with `PHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dirname` your root `index.php` file.

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

Or in [PHP 5.3+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
echo __DIR__;
```

Comment: For additional reference on magic constants: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @Darhazer Thanks for improve the answer. I like `__DIR__` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will get current server path.

```
echo getcwd();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Answer (score 0):

Also if you pass a filename you can use this one:

```
echo realpath("sample.php");
```

in my case it prints:

```
D:\Hosting\232325443\html\sample.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo __DIR__;
```

will print the directory of the running script

Comment: It will print **file** directory, not **current**.